# invalid grant type

Tags: apex, visualforce, oauth2

just need to understand what is the issue. i am not able to get the access token with parameter response_type for webserver flow.

Apex:---

```
public static void getaccesstoken(){
String clientId = '3MVG98RqVesxRgQ6mLzJ3Ah6LwMl7XWvdLirzijsSeEQo9yaJE1vVWrV.RLLGtLAzjTZWV0l9Y4DezE_VPWY5';
String clientSecret = '9086754825672118897';
string callbackurl='https://ap1.salesforce.com/customer/services/oauth2/callback/``';
String reqbody = 'response_type=code&client_id='+clientId+'&redirect_uri='+callbackurl+'&display=page';

Http h = new Http();
HttpRequest req = new HttpRequest();
req.setBody(reqbody);
req.setMethod('POST');
req.setEndpoint('https://test.salesforce.com/services/oauth2/token');//Note if my domain is set up use the proper domain name else use login.salesforce.com for prod or developer or test.salesforce.com for sandbox instance

HttpResponse res = h.send(req);
system.debug('--------'+res.getBody());
 showres = res.getBody();

  }
```

visualforce:-

```
<apex:page controller="accesstokenrest" >
<apex:form >
<apex:pageblock >
    <apex:commandbutton value="send http request" action="{!getaccesstoken}"/>
            <apex:commandbutton value="fetch case" action="{!fetch}" rerender="pbt"/>

   <b>ShowResponse</b>:-- {!showres}<br/>
   <b>AccessToken</b>:-- {!accessToken}<br/>
   <b>InstanceUrl</b>:--- {!sfdcInstanceUrl}

  <b>Body</b>:--- {!body}
    </apex:pageblock>
 </apex:form>
</apex:page>
```

Comment: Be careful about posting personal details in your question.

Comment: @martin.....sure thnx for your help. kindly help me with the above issue